# Floor option EVE risk: Sum of key rate shocks risks vs. the rates parallel shock risk

Tags: options, option-pricing, fixed-income, interest-rates, derivatives

Consider a model measuring the EVE risk (change in the economic value by shocking the rates; PV01) of a portfolio of vanilla interest rate floor options. Is there any reason for the EVE risk of a floor option under 1bp parallel shock of the rates being equal to the sum of EVE risks resulting from the 1bp shock of the key rates?